# C# OdbcConnection error for oracle g10

Tags: c#, oracle10g, odbc, handleerror

i am using c# odbc for oracle g10 when i run this code it gives me the following error please help thank you.

error is at line record = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

```
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection();
        try
        {
            connection = new OdbcConnection(String.Format("DSN={0};Uid={1};Pwd={2};", txtDsn.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text));
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("call {0}.GETACCOUNT(?,?)", txtDB.Text);
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            //stored procedure sql input paramaters. 
            OdbcParameter accountNumber = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACCOUNTNUMBER", OdbcType.VarChar);
            accountNumber.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = txtAccountNumber.Text;


        //output parameters
            OdbcParameter accountStatus = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACCOUNT_STATUS", OdbcType.VarChar, 50);
            accountStatus.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        try
        {
        if (!connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
        }
                int record = 0;
                record = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        try
        {
            txtResult.AppendText(string.Format("Account Status: {0} {1}", accountStatus.Value, Environment.NewLine));
        }
        Catch(Exception ex
            {
                        txtResult.AppendText(string.Format("Executing result Error{0} {1}{2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.Data));
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtResult.AppendText(string.Format("connection erorr  {0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           txtResult.AppendText((String.Format("retrive data fail: {0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)));
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```

connection erorr
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Couple of comments; 1) Given you have a connection error, have you tried a different connection string? See http://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/; in addition, you may want to try the Oracle specific .Net Data Provider (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html)

Comment: That style DSN is for a System DSN. Is there a System DSN setup on the machine and is the name correct when you pass it through.

Comment: yes, system DSN is setup, and it is connecting fine. the error comes when cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() invoked.